# Can l use PowerShell to update the property of entity in azure storage to null

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have retrieved an entity from my table. I want to set one of the property to null. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is No. You can't set a property's value to null.

Essentially Azure Table is a key/value pair storage. An entity contains attributes and each attribute must have a name, type and value and the value can't be null.

One thing you could do is remove that particular attribute from the entity. The approach for that would be:

1. Fetch the entity.
2. Remove the attribute from the entity for which you want to set the value to null.
3. Update the entity.